# How do I use multi tag filters in Django REST Framework API response?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

first of all I apologize if I did not ask a question using better words. I am building a DRF App, I have `Products` Model, `ProductSerializer` and `ProductsSummaryView`. Furthermore, I have Workspace Model (not going to talk about it as it is not related to the issue). Now, I want to return those products details in success response which are attached with a specific Workspace, filtered on some parameters.

What I have done:
I defined `filterset_fields` and `filter_backends`. It works fine. For example, if I go to this URL `{{domain}}/path/?country__title=Japan`, it filters the data for Japan and show me. But the problem is, I want to filter using multi-tag, such as let's say if I want to see details for Japan and Korea, so I want something like this `{{domain}}/path/?country__title=Japan&country__title=Korea`, but it is not working and it just returns all the details. I even tried adding empty list format in the URL and tried this URL `{{domain}}/path/?country__title[]=Japan&country__title[]=Korea`, but it still did not work.

Can anybody help me in this?

My `Product` Model is:

```
class Product(BaseModel):
    """Product model to store all prices of a product and
    related brand and countries it's available in"""
    product = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    fzg_segment = models.ForeignKey(
        FZGSegment, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True
    )
```

My `ProductSerializer` Serializer is:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for the part object"""
    fzg_segment = FZGSegmentSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            "id",
            "product",
            "fzg_segment",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("id",)
```

And my `ProductsSummaryView` API is:

```
class ProductsSummaryView(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    """Viewset to return data for products in a workspace"""
    serializer_class = serializers.ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsWorkspaceAdminPermission,)
    pagination_class = StandardSetPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = [
        "fzg_segment__title",
        "country__title",
    ]

    def get_queryset(self) -> models.Product:
        """Returns queryset of all the products of a workspace"""
        workspace = self.kwargs["workspace"]
        workspace = get_object_or_404(models.Workspace, pk=workspace)
        return workspace.products.all()
```

Can anyone help me and let me know what do I need to do in order to achieve desired functionality?

**UPDATE:**
I have created `filters.py` file as below:

```
# filters.py

import django_filters
from .models import Product

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    fzg_segment__title = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name="fzg_segment__title", lookup_expr='in')
    country__title = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name="country__title", lookup_expr='in')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            "fzg_segment__title",
            "country__title",
        ]
```

and I have update my `views.py` as below:

```
# views.py

class ProductsSummaryView(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    """Viewset to return data for products in a workspace"""
    serializer_class = serializers.ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsWorkspaceAdminPermission,)
    pagination_class = StandardSetPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = filters.ProductFilter

    def get_queryset(self) -> models.Product:
        """Returns queryset of all the products of a workspace"""
        workspace = self.kwargs["workspace"]
        workspace = get_object_or_404(models.Workspace, pk=workspace)
        queryset = workspace.products.all()
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
        return queryset
```

and I tried to use filters as following in the URL:

`{{domain]]/path/?country__title=Japan&country__title=Korea`

and

`{{domain]]/path/?country__title__in=Japan&country__title__in=Korea``

and

`{{domain]]/path/?country__title__in=Japan,Korea`

and

`{{domain]]/path/?country__title[]=Japan&country__title[]=Korea`

But all in vain, I am unable to use even single filter, leave the multiple one. What is wrong am I doing?

Comment: Have you solved it? What you need is `filterset_class` instead of `filterset_fields`. Then use `in` filterset. 
https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#baseinfilter

Comment: @MahrusKhomaini No I have not solved it. I have used `filterset_class` and used `in` as `lookup_expr` in `CharFilter` fields, but still all in vain. I updated my question and added updated code. Could you please have a look and let me know what is wrong I am doing?

Comment: I have added an answer below, please check. Hope can solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [BaseInFilter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#baseinfilter), example:

```
from django_filters.filters import BaseInFilter
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

class CharInFilter(BaseInFilter, filters.CharFilter):
    pass


class ProductFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    country = CharInFilter(field_name="country__title", lookup_expr='in')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["country"]
```

The params url like:
`/?country=Japan,Korea`

Comment: I did define the filters as you told in this answer in my `filters.py` file. Although the line `filters.CharInFilter(field_name="country__title", lookup_expr='in')` should actually be `CharInFilter(field_name="country__title", lookup_expr='in')`, but it still is not working. Are you sure that the params url should be `/?country=Japan,Korea` instead of `/?country_title=Japan,Korea`? BTW, I checked both ways and it still did not work.

Comment: Yes, param is `.?country=Japan,Kore` becasue i defnied `country = filters.CharInFilter(....`
I have tested in it works.

Comment: I edited asnwer, it should `country = CharInFilter(field_name="country__title", lookup_expr='in')`

Comment: Should I add the `class Meta` in the definition of `ProductFilterSet` as I have done in my updated question details?

Comment: I just edit, add class meta at answer above. Yes plese add class meta